# Deletion in a BST

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, double-pointer

Deletion is taking place inside function but not reflected in the `head` after returning from function. I'm using double pointer so I think it should.

**Code**

```
void delete(node **head,int key)
{
    int x;
    node *p=*head,*q=*head;
    while(p->data!=key)
    {
        q=p; //q will have the address of parent
        if(p->data>key)
            p=p->left;
        else
            p=p->right;
    }   
    if(p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL) //leaf
    {   
        p=NULL;
        return ;
    }
    if(p->left==NULL)
    {
        if(q->left&&q->left==p) //Check if the node to be deleted is a left/right child of parent
        {
            q->left=p->right;
            free(p);
            return;
        }
        if(q->right&&q->right==p)
        {
            q->right=p->right;
            free(p);
            return;
        }

    }
    if(p->left!=NULL && p->right!=NULL)
    {
        q=giveAddress(*head,inorderSuccessor(*head,key));   //give address find the address of the inorder successor
        p->data=q->data;
        free(q);
    }   




}
```

Function call : delete(&head,key);

Note : One thing I don't understand is if i change the condition inside leaf part of the above function it works for leaf.

```
if(p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL) //leaf
    {   
        if(q->left&&q->left==p) //Check if the node to be deleted is a left/right child of parent
        {
            q->left=NULL;
            free(p);
            return;
        }
        if(q->right&&q->right==p)
        {
            q->right=NULL;
            free(p);
            return;
        }

    }
```

It's okay since we are making the pointer of parent (left,right ) NULL . So it will delete the node. It will not free the memory location though , right?

**Correct me if I'm wrong**

So if we do `p=Null` it assigns a null value to p and parent->left is still holding the address to the node to be deleted. Hence ,it is not deleted.
Only the pointer p is changed, rest is okay!

But, in recursion we can do that..why?

Comment: If `key` is not in the tree, the first `while()` loop will fail by dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, so it should be checking the pointers. Then in `if(p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL)` you *have* found a match. You should delete the leaf, but why are you expecting the `head` to change (unless the head is the parent of the leaf)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm making sure that `delete()` is only called is the key exists in the tree.So I'm not checking it here and it won't dereference a null pointer. I'm using that condition to check if the found node is a leaf.

Comment: @WeatherVane What if the node found to be deleted is not a leaf..say has 1 child , or maybe two then we have to find inorder predecessor / successor.

Comment: If the node has one child that's easy - just link the child to the node's parent and free the node. If the node has two children it's trickier. You can patch out one of the children as before, then follow that branch to find where to re-insert the other branch you are losing. In the case of keeping the left branch, you follow its right-pointers until you find a NULL. In the case of keeping the right branch, you follow its left-pointers until you find a NULL. The only times you need to change `head` are 1) when the node you are deleting has no parent node and 2) when you re-balance a tree.